# Changing radial shading

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, tcolorbox

I'm trying to change the radial shading given:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{XCharter}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[x11names,svgnames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[tikz]{bclogo}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}



\definecolor{recyclecolor}{RGB}{154,84,158}

\makeatletter

\tcbset{%
  decoration downshift/.store in={\decoration@downshift},
  decoration radius/.store in={\decoration@radius},
  decoration recycle radius/.store in={\decoration@recyclecircleradius},
  decoration dot radius/.store in={\decoration@dotradius},
  decoration content/.store in={\decoration@content},
  decoration colour/.store in={\decoration@colour},
}

\tcbset{recyclebox/.style={decoration radius=0.5cm,decoration downshift=-0.5cm}}

\tcbset{learnthisbox/.style={%
    decoration radius=0.5cm,
    decoration downshift=-0.5cm,
    decoration content={\bclampe},
    decoration colour=blue}
}


\newtcolorbox{recyclebox}[2][]{%
  recyclebox,
  decoration recycle radius={0.6*\decoration@radius},
  decoration dot radius={0.04*\decoration@radius},
  decoration colour=recyclecolor,
  breakable,
  enhanced jigsaw,
  leftrule=1.5pt,
  fonttitle={\bfseries\large},
  title={\MakeUppercase{Recycle!}},
  #1,
  attach title to upper={{\bfseries\large #2}\par},
  interior style={shading=radial,inner color=tcbcol@back!0,outer color=tcbcol@back},
  underlay unbroken and first={%
    \draw[tcbcol@frame,line width=\kvtcb@left@rule,fill=tcbcol@back] ($(frame.north west) + (\kvtcb@left@rule-0.03pt,\decoration@downshift)$) arc [start angle=90.0,end angle=270.0,radius=\decoration@radius] node[midway,inner sep=0pt] (dottedcircle) {};
    \foreach \x in {1,...,12} {%
      \draw[fill=tcbcol@back,opacity=4*(\x/12),tcbcol@frame] ($(dottedcircle) + (\decoration@radius,0cm)+(120+\x*30:\decoration@recyclecircleradius)$) circle (\decoration@dotradius);
    };
  },
  colframe={\decoration@colour},
  colback={tcbcol@frame!30},
  coltitle={tcbcol@frame!150},
}


\makeatother




\begin{document}

\begin{recyclebox}[decoration radius={0.4cm},decoration dot radius=0.03cm]{~title}
\blindtext[1]
\end{recyclebox}


\end{document}
```

What I want is to increase the radial shading so as the white fill be bigger.

The code shows:

[image: a]

Is there another kind of shading? Rectangular? How to do it?

Comment: And I put so many effort to provide the radial shading in there, now you want to drop it :-(

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I don't want to drop it. I just want to see if I can increase the radius for the white fill; I do appreciate your posts! I wouldn't do nothing if it weren't for you!

Comment: Keyword: functionalshading.

Comment: You can define a custom shading to replace `radial`.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/286984/can-tikz-implement-multi-stop-gradient-fills-with-adjustable-positions/286994#286994. (Not the shading you want, but shows how to do it.)

Answer (score 3):

The key to change a radial shading is `\pgfdeclareradialshading`, see the `pgf` manual at `109.2.2 Radial Shadings`

```
\pgfdeclareradialshading[inner color,middle color, outer color]{ustanakradial}{\pgfpoint{0.0cm}{0.0cm}}%
{ color(0)=(inner color);
  color(10bp)=(middle color);
  color(28bp)=(outer color)
}
```

This defines a radial shading named `ustanakradial`, with some symbolic color names that are applied on the circles with relevant radii. The values of `10pt` and `28pt` are 'guesses' only. Don't exaggerate them.

The center of the shading is fixed here to `\pgfpoint{0cm}{0cm}`.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{XCharter}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[x11names,svgnames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[tikz]{bclogo}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}



\definecolor{recyclecolor}{RGB}{154,84,158}

\makeatletter


\tikzset{%
  ustanakradial inner color/.code={\colorlet{inner color}{#1}},
  ustanakradial middle color/.code={\colorlet{middle color}{#1}},
  ustanakradial outer color/.code={\colorlet{outer color}{#1}},
}

\tcbset{%
  decoration downshift/.store in={\decoration@downshift},
  decoration radius/.store in={\decoration@radius},
  decoration recycle radius/.store in={\decoration@recyclecircleradius},
  decoration dot radius/.store in={\decoration@dotradius},
  decoration content/.store in={\decoration@content},
  decoration colour/.store in={\decoration@colour},
}

\tcbset{recyclebox/.style={decoration radius=0.5cm,decoration downshift=-0.5cm}}

\tcbset{learnthisbox/.style={%
    decoration radius=0.5cm,
    decoration downshift=-0.5cm,
    decoration content={\bclampe},
    decoration colour=blue}
}


\pgfdeclareradialshading[inner color,middle color, outer color]{ustanakradial}{\pgfpoint{0.0cm}{0.0cm}}%
{ color(0)=(inner color);
  color(10bp)=(middle color);
  color(28bp)=(outer color)
}




\newtcolorbox{recyclebox}[2][]{%
  recyclebox,
  decoration recycle radius={0.6*\decoration@radius},
  decoration dot radius={0.04*\decoration@radius},
  decoration colour=recyclecolor,
  breakable,
  enhanced jigsaw,
  leftrule=1.5pt,
  fonttitle={\bfseries\large},
  title={\MakeUppercase{Recycle!}},
  #1,
  attach title to upper={{\bfseries\large #2}\par},
  interior style={shading=ustanakradial,ustanakradial inner color=tcbcol@back!0,ustanakradial middle color=tcbcol@back!0,ustanakradial outer color=tcbcol@back},
  underlay unbroken and first={%
    \draw[tcbcol@frame,line width=\kvtcb@left@rule,fill=tcbcol@back] ($(frame.north west) + (\kvtcb@left@rule-0.03pt,\decoration@downshift)$) arc [start angle=90.0,end angle=270.0,radius=\decoration@radius] node[midway,inner sep=0pt] (dottedcircle) {};
    \foreach \x in {1,...,12} {%
      \draw[fill=tcbcol@back,opacity=4*(\x/12),tcbcol@frame] ($(dottedcircle) + (\decoration@radius,0cm)+(120+\x*30:\decoration@recyclecircleradius)$) circle (\decoration@dotradius);
    };
  },
  colframe={\decoration@colour},
  colback={tcbcol@frame!30},
  coltitle={tcbcol@frame!150},
}


\makeatother




\begin{document}

\begin{recyclebox}[decoration radius={0.4cm},decoration dot radius=0.03cm]{~title}
\blindtext[1]
\end{recyclebox}


\end{document}
```

[image]